# Unable to bind view model from collection using Knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I would like to bind the view model item to a part of HTML from collection which is bound to another HTML in the page. 

Here is my sample HTML and JS code:

```
<div>
<div style="width: 200px; float: left;" class="roundedBorder">
    <fieldset id="fieldsetCategory">
        <legend>Category</legend>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Category Name</th>    
                </tr>    
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: categories">
                <tr data-bind="click: onCategoryClick.bind($data, $parent)">
                    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="divCategoryData" style="width: 200px; float: right;" class="roundedBorder">
    <fieldset id="fieldsetCategoryInfo">
        <legend>Category Information</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Catgory Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Catgory Address:</td>
                <td>
                    <strong data-bind="text: address"></strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CategoryModel(name, address) {
        var self = this;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    function CategoryViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.categories = [
            new CategoryModel("Category 1", "Delhi"),
            new CategoryModel("Category 2", "Gurgaon"),
            new CategoryModel("Category 3", "Noida"),
            new CategoryModel("Category 4", "Ghaziabad")
        ];
    }

    self.onCategoryClick = function () {
        var model = this;
        alert(model.name + " " + model.address);
        ko.applyBindings(model, "divCategoryData");

    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        ko.applyBindings(new CategoryViewModel());
        ko.applyBindings(new CategoryModel(), "divCategoryData");
    });

</script>
```

I want to bind the CategoryModel object to "divCategoryData" html section. As you can see, model is being passed to the click of row event. However, I am unable to display the category name & address on selection from the list.

Can someone guide me the code snippet of "self.onCategoryClick" event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I wouldn't try to rebind a div on each selection change.

I suggest to create an selectedCategory observable that contains the selected Category.

```
function CategoryModel(name, address) {
    var self = this;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}

function CategoryViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.categories = [
    new CategoryModel("Category 1", "Delhi"),
    new CategoryModel("Category 2", "Gurgaon"),
    new CategoryModel("Category 3", "Noida"),
    new CategoryModel("Category 4", "Ghaziabad")];

    self.selectedCategory = ko.observable();

    self.onCategoryClick = function (model) {
        //alert(model.name + " " + model.address);
        self.selectedCategory(model);

    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new CategoryViewModel());
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sr59/2/) for demo

I hope it helps.